# When I press the card how to set card data into text field in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I press my card, I want to set my card data into the text field.
my Card Widget and it's another stateful widget. And I need to set this card data into my text field

[image: This is how it's look.]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
 body: ListView(
 shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
       Form(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "CupCake Name",
                controller: cupCake,
                onChanged: (cupcake) {
                  cupcakeName = cupcake;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]
         LoadData(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**This is my Card Widget and it's another stateful widget. And I need to set this card data into my text field**

```
class LoadData extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadData({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadDataState createState() => _LoadDataState();
}

class _LoadDataState extends State<LoadData> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: ListView(
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => {print("Test")},
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          data['cupcake_name'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 4),
                        Text(
                          data['description'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                     );
            }).toList(),
           ),
       }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at flutter [simple state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up). Basically as you have state that is shared and pertinent to a sub-tree of your widget tree you should encapsulate and lift that state as high as the first widget that needs to interact with it.

1 create the model which will handle the needed state

```
class CupCakeState extends ChangeNotifier {
  CupCake? cupcake;

void selectCupcake(CupCake newCake){
this.cupCake=newCupcake;
notifyListeners();
}
```

2 Provide the model in the widget tree

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CupCakeState(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
```

3 Now you can use it either reading the context.
In your card:

```
class _LoadDataState extends State<LoadData> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: ListView(
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => {context.read<CupCakeState>().selectCupcake(CupCake(name:data['cupcake_name'],price:data['cupcake_price']))},
...
```

Or creating a widget that rebuilds everytime you call notifylisteners()

```
Consumer<CupCakeState>(
  builder: (context, cupcpakeState, child) {
cupcake.value=cupcpakeState.price;//assign the price to the controller

  return TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "CupCake Name",
                controller: cupCake,
                onChanged: (cupcake) {
                  cupcakeName = cupcake;
                },
              ),
  },
)
```